# How can I produce this XML document using an XSLT transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

Original XML:

```
<EbsSendOTPResponse>
<ResponseHeader>
<GUID/>
<GUID2/>
</ResponseHeader>
</EbsSendOTPResponse>
```

Transformed to:

```
<EbsSendOTPResponse type="group">
<ResponseHeader type="group">
<GUID/>
<GUID2/>
</ResponseHeader>
</EbsSendOTPResponse>
```

I want to add the type="group" attiribute to the parent tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:if test="*">
      <!--
      <xsl:if test="name()='ResponseHeader' or name()='EbsSendOTPResponse'">
      -->
        <xsl:attribute name="type">group</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I have diffrent tags without 'ResponseHeader' and 'EbsSendOTPResponse'. I need catch the parent node and add the my attiribute( type="group" ).

Comment: If I understand well, try to replace test condition with "<xsl:if test="*">"

Answer (score 0):

Please use this below code, just match the template and add the @type attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="EbsSendOTPResponse">
        <EbsSendOTPResponse typpe="group">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </EbsSendOTPResponse>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ResponseHeader">
        <ResponseHeader typpe="group">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ResponseHeader>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I have diffrent tags without 'ResponseHeader' and 'EbsSendOTPResponse'. I need catch the parent node and add the my attiribute( type="group" ).